# John the Ripper - Zip Password help - Latter half digit command advice

Tags: hash, password-cracking, john-the-ripper, zip

I'm trying to use John to recover some old ZIP files with a password I remember half. One half being a word, the latter half being a mix of four to six digits.
I remember the word, but not the digits after it, what line of code/command can I enter for John to start with the right password, then only to find the right number combination?

Answer (score 4):

A mask attack would be the simplest way - you can use `?d` to represent an unknown digit. So something like this for four digits:

`john input.txt --mask="word?d?d?d?d"`

And then adding on more `?d` for additional digits if needed.

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: @LEGEND-001 if this answered your question, you can click the green check mark to accept the answer